# Deserializing Json to C# class returns null

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have this code that calls up a PHP that returns a Json

```
string str = "https://url/file.php";
        string[] cID = new string[] { "act=qwjFpPXuGexZBHDJEreZrAUH&CID=", "&username=", Username, "&password=", Password };
        string str1 = string.Concat(cID);
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Proxy = null;
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string str2 = webClient.UploadString(str, str1).Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Trim();

            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Information>>(str2);
```

str2 returns this Json

[{"username":"xxxxxx","email":"xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com","plan":"0","activationdate":"","terminationdate":""}]

Which is what I want but when i try to pass it to this class it sends nothing:

```
public class Information
{
    
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public string activationdate { get; set; }
    public string terminationdate { get; set; }

    public Information()
    {
        
    }
}
```

And if I try to do this

```
label11.Text = Information.username;
```

I get "null" on the label  and this error: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property.

What am I doing wrong and how can I deserialize correctly to the class to be able to show the contents of the class into the labels?.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the value to a variable and use the variables property to assign the value to your label.

```
List<Information> myVariable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Information>>(str2);

label11.Text = myVariable[0].username;
```

You cannot simply access properties of the class without first creating an instance of it.